# Fastest data structure for numerically indexed data structure?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am using regular python 2.79 and only want to use the standard libaries.  I want to create what is basically a two dimensional array, where each cell referenced by two dimensions will point a small dictionary of miscellaneous data.  I want the fastest way to access the cell containing the dictionary.  The data will have two integer indexes by which I can reference each cell.  I will already know the x and y (let's call them..)

1) the x and y elements will have permissible values between -58600 and +58600.

2) not every cell will contain information, but i need to quickly look up and get cell data by numerical x,y index.

3) the contents of the data cell could be any size or configuration and could change over time, as I upgrade code or include new parameters, etc.

My first thought was a nested dictionary such that

```
dictionary_structure[x][y]["data"]
```

would look up the data .. or test for exists by

```
if "data" in dictionary_structure[x][y]:
```

What sort of data structure should i use for the fastest lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the performance will improve if you only have one top-level dictionary, rather than one for each dimension. Here are a few possibilities:

Use tuples:

```
if (x, y) in dictionary_structure:
    print(dictionary_structure[(x, y)]["data"])
```

Multiply one coordinate by the number of possible values for it, and add to the other (your keys are now integers; the multiplication ensures that no unique combination of `x` and `y` will become the same key - but do wrap the key computation up in a function; you can also use division and modulo to extract x and y from a key):

```
key = 117201 * x + y
if key in dictionary_structure:
    print(dictionary_structure[key]["data"])
```

I don't know which of these will be faster in your situation; you need to measure it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filter at innermost level. Here are a few implementations:

https://github.com/bitly/dablooms

https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap

https://bitbucket.org/crankycoder/hydra/src

Very fast processing, data size doesn't matter because of internal hashing techniques. However false positives are there - so you need to verify whether this is suitable for your exact problem or not.

Comment: False positives?  What does that mean exactly?  Will it "mix up" cells like giving me cell 34,56 when i looked up 37,42? or tell me cell 37,42 does not have data, etc?

Comment: False positive means that it may say that a particular "data" is there even when there is not (though very rarely). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Comment: But if "data" is present, it will definitely return true.

Comment: I asked for Python with no non-standard libraries...?  I can't use add on type stuff.  has to be straight python code I can write... what sort of structure is fastest.